# Connecting PCB power planes and polygons

Tags: pcb, pcb-layers

i am making a 4 layer PCB board and in that the inner two layers are ground planes between top and bottom signal layers. I want to know do i have to connect the top layer(signal layer) with ground plane (layer 2) and bottom layer (signal layer) to ground plane (layer 3)?

second thing i am very confused about polygons is that e.g if a have a two layer board (only top and bottom signal layers) and i use a polygon on top layer and connect it to ground of top layer, do i need to route/connect ground pins/pads on top layer of my PCB or they will automatically connect to ground polygon on top layer and become grounded??

last thing is if i am routing a board and used ground planes in it. is there a need to add polygon??

Comment: You can just use normal vias. If you have fills on the outer layers that are 0V, yes, you want to knIt them with vias to the groundplane, otherwise they may become antennas.

Comment: The only reason you would need to use microvia's is if you are using BGA's with a very small pitch such that the aspect ratio cannot be achieved for the requested via size.

Comment: @JonRB ok but i want to know that if i am habving ground plane below my signal plane do i have to connect both using vias or there is no need to connect signal layer with ground plane

Comment: @JonRB  i have edited the question can you please look and think you can give me a clear answer.